# C++ zlib: Trouble reading a zlib buffer with <fstream>:

Tags: c++, zlib

So I'm trying to make use of zlib in C++ using Visual Studio 2019, to extract the contents from a specific file format. According to the documentation that I'm following, this file format is consisted mainly consisted of values that's consisted of "32-bit (4-byte) little-endian signed integers", and within several sections of the file there's also blocks of data that is compressed by zlib to save space.
But I believe that's not relevant to my problem, I'm having trouble with just simply using zlib.

I should note that I'm unfamiliar to using fstream and more specifically, zlib. I can guess `uncompress()` may be the function I'm looking since the number for the compressed bytes is read before I can even call it. It's not unlikely the issue could be related to the former library.

But I do believe I'm not putting in the buffer properly (or maybe not even reading it from the file properly), as I'm getting either syntax errors for incorrect types, the program crashing, and most importantly, unable to get the blocks of the uncompressed data. I can tell it's not working properly as it's returning `Z_STREAM_ERROR` (-2) or `Z_DATA_ERROR` (-3) from the call, not `Z_OK` (0). The program at least reads the 32-bit data correctly, at least.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "zlib.h"

using namespace std;

//Basically it works like this.

int main()
{
    streampos size;
    unsigned char memblock;
    char* memblock2;
    Bytef memblock3;
    Bytef memblock_res;

    int ret;
    int res=0;
    uint32_t a;

    ifstream file("not_a_real_file.lol", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
    std::cout << "Format Identifier: " << a << "\n";
    
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
    std::cout << "File Version: " << a << "\n";

    //A bunch of other 32-bit values be here, would be redudent to put them all.

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
        std::cout << "Length of Zlib Block: " << a << "\n";

    //Anyways, this is where things get really weird. I'm using 'a' to determine the length of bytes, and I know it should be stored into it's own variable.
    char* membuffer = new char[a];
    file.read(membuffer, a);

    uLongf zaz;
    res=uncompress(&memblock_res, &zaz, (unsigned char*)(&membuffer), a);
    if (res==Z_OK)
            std::cout << "Good!\n";
    std::cout << "This resulted in " << (int)res << ", it's got this many bytes: " << zaz << "\n";
    //It should be Z_DATA_ERROR with 0 bytes returned; it's obviously not the desired results.

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
    std::cout << "Value after Block: " << a << "\n";
    //At least it seems the 32-bit value that comes after the block is correctly read.
    file.close();
    }
}
```

Either I'm using `read()` incorrectly, or don't know how to properly convert the data into the use for `uncompress()`. Or maybe I'm using the wrong functions; I honestly have no clue. I spent hours trying to figure this out from looking up things, but having no avail.

Comment: You don't appear to be initializing `memblock_res` or `zaz` before passing them to `uncompress()`. `memblock_res` needs to point to a chunk of memory `zaz` bytes long that's big enough to hold the decompressed data.

Comment: The uncompress call is completely wrong. Only the fourth parameter is correct. You need to allocate some memory for the first param, you need to pass a pointer the amount of memory allocated for the second parameter. you need to pass a pointer to the memory to be decompressed as the third param (not a pointer to a pointer like you are doing). If you are using casts in your call to uncompress then you are doing something wrong. Finally you need to be prepared for the situation that you may not have allocated enough memory. You need to test for that and allocate extra memory if necessary.

Comment: Here's a suggestion, *practise* using compress and uncompress on some toy data first. compress a short string (e.g. "hello world") and see if you can get the same string back using uncompress. Only when you've mastered this apply what you've learned to your main program. If you get stuck on the practise program then at least you have something simple you can post to stack overflow for more advice.